# Suspend Layout Resume Layout

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, onpaint

I am having a user control with a flow layout panel. This control can have one or more same controls. This hierarchy can grow to many levels.

Initially I am adding the Root Control. Then Controls are added to the root control (flow layout panel).

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    SuspendLayout();
    AddControls(containerControl1, _rootFileNode.Nodes);
    ResumeLayout(false);
    PerformLayout();
}

private void AddControls(IContainerNode parent, ICollection<INode> childNodes)
{
    foreach (var node in childNodes)
    {
        switch (node.FileType)
        {
            case FileType.File:
                parent.AddNode(node);
                break;

            case FileType.Directory:
                {
                    var container = parent.AddNode(node) as IContainerNode;
                    AddControls(container, node.Nodes);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Code which actually adds the control (ContainerControl class).

```
public DesignerBase AddNode(INode node)
{
    //Get the corresponding Control
    //Simple User Control with label and RTF- If File Node
    //User Control with FlowLayout and other controls - If Folder Node

    var designerBlock = DesignerBlockFactory.Get(node);
    flowLayoutMain.Controls.Add(designerBlock);
    return designerBlock;
}
```

The problem is, I am having multiple levels of controls. But it seems that the immediate container inside the root container is not resizing properly. And so the nodes are partially shown. If I enable the AutoResize property of the user controls then the User Control is resizing but with bad flickering.

Is there any way to force the contrpls to resize immediately. I tried Suspend layout in the Form and also in the User Control

**Fix:**
I did not actually fix this issue. I enabled auto resize property to true. This caused bad flickering during form load.

To reduce the flicker, I added the following code in the Form.

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

This will show the form once all the controls are loaded. So there will be an initial delay before the form load.

Comment: I think your ResumeLayout(false); PerformLayout(); may be in the wrong order, try switching those and see what happens.

Comment: Does it works when you supsend/resume the layout of the parent node inside the AddControls: parent.SuspendLayout() and parent.ResumeLayout()

Comment: No.. Its still not working.. I tried the following

case FileType.File:
 (parent as UserControl).SuspendLayout();
 parent.AddNode(node);
 
 (parent as UserControl).ResumeLayout(false);
 (parent as UserControl).PerformLayout();
 break;

case FileType.Directory:
 {
  (parent as UserControl).SuspendLayout();
  var container = parent.AddNode(node) as IContainerNode;
  
  (parent as UserControl).ResumeLayout(false);
  parent as UserControl).PerformLayout();
  
  AddControls(container, node.Nodes);  
  break;
 }

Comment: Well, maybe we can tweak the design a little bit, move the code out of Form2_Load and into Form2's constructor after the InitializeComponent call, that way all of the rendering should be complete and all we need to wait for is the painting of it.

Comment: Still no change.. As I mention earlier, initially the controls are overlapped.. I suspect the width and the height is not calculated properly.. After few resizing it renders correctly.. I have implemented a method that will recusrively set the Height of the controls and its working.. Still looking for a proper solution..

Comment: Looks like we have [the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834687/top-docking-controls-more-than-32768-pixels): when docking controls with a total height over 32768 pixels, the lower controls no longer dock properly.

Comment: See my update. Please share your answer if you have fixed this.