# Top-docking controls more than 32768 pixels

Tags: c#, winforms, docking

I have a WinForms application that allows you to edit documents. Each document is made of chapters and each chapter holds a collection of RTF blocks. The RTF blocks are loaded in a `PanelControl` using `Dock = DockStyle.Top`.

The problem is that when the total height of a chapter gets too large (estimating > 32768 pixels) the lower blocks are not properly docked: they appear behind one another. When trying to isolate the problem I noticed that this also happens with simpler controls like a `LabelControl`.

Things I tried are methods like `Refresh()`, `Invalidate()` and `PerformLayout`: they will **not** resolve the issue.

What **does** help is resizing the form. After that all controls are laid out correctly.

Can anyone help on how to solve this without resizing the form?

Attached a [simple demo-project](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/mW8UnMrik/) that illustrates the problem.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `Int16.MaxValue = 32767` - perhaps the underlying reason?

Comment: @Martin: my thought exactly, but it doesn't explain why controls are layed out correctly after I resize the form.

Comment: Well, it's a good question, but this design sounds like a recipe for resource overruns.  I do not believe Windows (handles, etc.) are designed to accomodate this much allocation.

Comment: I'm not really surprised here. WinForms (and the GDI in general) is often behaving unpredictably if one tries to use coordinates outside a 16 bit range. Try to avoid that.

Comment: @Martin: See my (a bit extended) answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment above (seems really to be the problem here):

WinForms (and the GDI in general) is often behaving unpredictably if one tries to use coordinates outside a 16 bit range. Try to avoid that. In the range of possible problems are things just not getting drawn at all, OverflowExceptions at unexpected code positions etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to you take decision to change this layout, I suggest you to take another approach on showing/editing the documents chapters with some kind of pagination or collapsing RTF blocks into a menu and showing only current.

You see.. it makes a sense the height value be a integer 16-bit value.
A screen is way more tiny than this.
As panel height increases to such a high size. You see that using scroll bar will become very very sensible.. and it's not a good thing.

Content with size 2x, 3x, 5x being scrolled is usable to user. But scrolling a content with height (~32768) of at least (using good resolution monitor w/ window maximized) in optimal case 32x the size of window is very uncomfortable.

Plus, I believe that the productivity of user will decrease due to brain difficulty in locate "things" in a increasing collection of "things".

Comment: Ideally, that seems to be the best way to go. However, estimating the impact of these changes, I was actually hoping for a simpler solution.